# Routes in Engine mounted on subdomain do not inherit the constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, rails-engines

## Setup

Our current Rails app is made out of sub-apps that are mounted as engines. Typically these engines are mounted on a subdomain in the main `routes.rb` file as follows

```
mount MySubApp::Engine => '/', as: :sub_app, constraints: {subdomain: 'sub_app'}
```

## The Problem

Routes within `MySubApp`'s `routes.rb` file **do not** get the subdomain when using the named `_url` helpers. For example the following in `apps/my_sub_app/config/routes.rb`

```
MySubApp::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :foos
end
```

gives us `sub_app.foo_url(5)` but it results in

> http://**www**.example.com/foos/5

when we want

> http://**sub_app**.example.com/foos/5

## tl;dr

How can I get the engine's mounting constraints passed to its named routes?

## EDIT: A Workaround

While I'd still prefer a better solution, the following will work. You can wrap all the routes in each of the sub apps `routes.rb` files that could be mounted on a subdomain like so

```
MySubApp::Engine.routes.draw do
  constraints Rails.application.routes.named_routes[:sub_app].constraints do
    resources :foos
  end
end
```

## EDIT 2: A much less desirable workaround

A commenter (since deleted?) pointed out you can pass a `subdomain` option to the helpers but we'd like to avoid having to use `sub_app.foo_url(5, {subdomain: 'sub_app'})` for every cross subdomain link. Even if we moved the subdomain name into an ENV var and made a wrapper, this is not DRY.

Comment: Are you looking for multi-tenancy? If so, there's a Railscast for that, but it's pro. http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes?view=asciicast. Personally, I've never worked with them so I can't help you I just saw this episode a while back and am passing it along if it is in fact what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @MCB. I will check out that video when I can and update this if it provides any good leads.

Comment: I just saw the Railscast and it's not what we're looking for :/. We actually have multiple apps living as engines within one Rails app. Each of the engines is mounted with a subdomain constraint but that same constraint is not carried over to the engines' individual route files.

Comment: Have you tried this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?

Comment: @Surya thanks for letting me know about the video but it's not quite what we're looking for. Our more ideal solution has the subdomain constraint inherited by the engines so that all of their `_url` helpers are aware of and use a subdomain. As of right now, they don't know they should use one.

Comment: @Aaron: Are you looking for just a DRY-way of doing this? If that's the case then, all I can think of is, first you setup that `UrlHelper` shown in railscasts. Then, create an another helper method(maybe in `UrlHelper` itself)??: `def domain_url_for(subdomain = nil, options =nil) subdomain ? url_for(options) : url_for(options(:subdomain => subdomain)) end` maybe here you'll have to figure out how to call url helper with subdomain in else part, later, you can call it with: `domain_url_for('sub_app', foo_url)` I'm not sure though, buddy.

Comment: @Surya Thanks! I appreciate the ideas. My first work around is the DRYest way I have so far. I was just surprised that if you have a Rails engine with it's own routes, the helper methods that get generated will not know about a subdomain if the engine is mounted on one. I was hoping Rails would know to pass that information along.

Answer (score 1):

check out the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) it says you can do it by

```
namespace :Engine do
  resources :controller, :methods
end
```

the Engine is just name spacing your code

Comment: Thanks @bobbdelsol but this will just allow top level name-spacing. It won't effect subdomains at all.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron not sure if you ever got this fixed, but look into the

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length
```

setting (on the engine's config).  I'm not sure how it'll react with engines, but in our case it lets us handle the case of sub-subdomains for our staging server (so when we use the `_url` helpers with the staging server it correctly does `subdomain.staging.domain.com`, rather than `subdomain.domain.com`).